Zombie Outbreak movie with a cure
I need help identifying the name of this film. 
PLOT: 
It's about a zombie outbreak somewhere in the city the plot starts then it revolves the surviving group hiding in a cabin until the zombies follow them.
Due to the outbreak, the government tries to use a health patient data to find a immune patient whose blood can create a cure. One woman is immune and a prefect candidate and hence she is accompanied by some men to be delivered safely.
Plot points: 

A woman is immune whose blood can create a cure.
That woman is accompanied by a mercenary who is infected but the virus is suppressed due to some drug.
At the end the mercenary guy end up staying and sacrificing along with another guy of the surviving group to fight off (using common weapon like a bat or a crowbar) the zombie horde while the woman gets rescued near the boat shore. 

MOVIE YEAR: Somewhere between 2000 and 2010
The movies in the following list is not the movie I'm talking about:

Resident Evil 
  Dawn of the dead 
  Train to Busan 
  Doomsday 
  Contagion 
  Rec 
  The Crazies 
  Berlin Undead 
  World War z 
  I am legend  


I don't know, but you could go through this list, maybe it will be helpful (sort by year): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zombie_films

Is this a Hollywood movie? What language was it in? Were there any recognizable actors, or distinguishing traits like hair color / height / build?

I am not sure if it was a Hollywood movie. The language was English, I can't see to remember the actors since it was a  while ago and have watched a lot of the zombie films. Although it if helps, it's not in the Wikipedia Zombie list as I went through every film listed in there but some zombie films are not even listed there.  I appreciate the suggestions though.
